Cohomology of roots of unity vs cohomology of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$
Let $K$ be a local field of chracteristic zero and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I want to see whether the cohomology groups $H^1(Gal(\bar{K}/K); \mu_n)$ and $H^1(Gal(\bar{K}/K); \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ have the same cardinality. Here, $G = Gal(\bar{K}/K)$ acts on $\mu_n \subset \bar{K}$ by applying automorphisms to roots of unity and it acts trivially on $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Obviously, if we have $\mu_n \subset K$ this results in the same action.
After applying cohomology to the short exact sequences $1 \to \mu_n \cap L \to L^\times \to (L^\times)^n \to 1$ for $L/K$ finite and taking the colimit, we know $H^1(G; \mu_n) = K^\times / (K^\times)^n$, which we know to be finite of cardinality $n \cdot \vert\mu_n \cap K \vert \cdot p^{\vert K : \mathbb{Q_p}\vert v_p(n)}$.
Also $H^1(G; \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) = Hom_{cont}(G, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ and one can show that for any $d \vert n$ there is a 1:1-correspondece between cyclic extensions $L/K$ of degree $d$ and cyclic subgroups $H \leqslant Hom_{cont}(G, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ of order $d$. But from this it follows that $Hom_{cont}(G, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is also finite: Every element is $d$-torsion for some $d \vert n$, hence if $Hom_{cont}(G, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ was infinite, we would have infinitely many extensions $L/K$ of degree dividing $n$. This can not be the case though, since by local class field theory all of these would correspond to different subgroups $H \leqslant K^\times / (K^\times)^n$ and the latter group is finite.
Using a similar technique, I developed a proof for the cardinalities being equal in the case that $n$ is a prime $q$:
Let $\Phi_a$ and $\Phi_b$ denote the number of cyclic subgroups (of order $q$) of $K^\times / (K^\times)^q$ and $Hom_{cont}(G, \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})$, respectively. Then the cardinalities of both groups can be calculated as $1 + \Phi_a (q-1)$ and $1 + \Phi_b (q-1)$. Concerning $\Phi_a$ and $\Phi_b$ local CFT tells us $\Phi_b = $ #cyclic extensions $L/K$ of degree $q =$ #extensions $L/K$ of degree $q = $ #subgroups $H \leqslant K^\times$ of index $q =$ #subgroups $H \leqslant K^\times / (K^\times)^q$ of index $q =$ #subgroups $H \leqslant K^\times / (K^\times)^q$ of order $q = \Phi_a$. Hence we get the statement.
My first question is: Is this proof correct?
My second question, as you would guess, is how you handle the general case. I tried using the inflation restriction sequence with $F = K(\mu_n)$ but could not come to a conclusion.

If you get to use local class field theory, I would argue as follows:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
H^1(K, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) &= \text{Hom}(G_K, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \\
&= \text{Hom}(G_K^{\text{ab}}, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \\
&= \text{Hom}(\widehat{K}^\times, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \\
&= \text{Hom}(K^\times, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \\
&= \text{Hom}(K^\times/K^{\times n}, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}).
\end{aligned}
$$
The equalities in the big stack follow respectively from: the definition of $H^1$, the fact that the target is abelian, the main theorem of LCFT, the fact that maps out of the profinite completion to a finite group are maps out of the original group to that group, and the fact that $n$th powers have to map to $0$. You then have to argue that $\text{Hom}(A, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ has the same cardinality as $A$ for any finitely generated abelian $n$-torsion group $A$.
(I believe your proof is correct too in the case where $n$ is prime.)
It would be nice to see if there is a proof with less machinery. I'm wondering if you can get it from inflation-restriction, Hilbert 90, and the fact that $\text{Gal}(K(\zeta_n)/K)$ is cyclic.

Thanks a lot! This is pretty smooth. I think a proof using the tools you listed at the end of your answer should be possible, or atleast it seems intuitive to me. Maybe one can show that both restriction maps have the same image in $H^1(K(\zeta_n); \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$?
